# Composite to USB/VGA Converter Box

Tags: audio, composite-video

I wanted to get a gift for a friend, one of his old favorite games. The problem is, he doesn't have a TV, only computer monitors. (DVI+DSUB)  I would like to get him a Playstation that can hookup to his monitor for video and speakers.

I was looking at this [converter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?%20Item=N82E16815153010), and not sure if this is what I will need.

I don't understand if sound comes in on VGA or USB or if this idea is even possible.

Comment: Which PlayStation are you getting? PS1, PS2, or PS3?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, it is for PS1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the linked device won't work - it isn't a converter.  It is a media player, it will display your pictures video's etc. on USB drives on your TV.

However this [RCA, S-VIDEO, VGA TO VGA Converter](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011407&p_id=4722&seq=1&format=2) will.

Comment: Wow, thank you.  It even had a link to a 3.5mm adapter for sound.  Thank you shf301 :)